# How do I swap out a character in the nicknames of all members with a certain role?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command that replaces all dashes (`-`) with a `⍭` character in the nicknames of all members with a role named "tokuchi".

Here is what I have so far:

```
exports.run = async (client, member, message, args) => {
    let tokuchi = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "tokuchi");
    let tokaci = message.guild.members.filter(member => {
        return member.roles.some(r=>["tokuchi"].includes(r.name));
    });
    const Tokuchi = tokaci.user.username.replace(`⍭`, '-');
    tokuchi.members.forEach(u => {
        u.setNickname(Tokuchi);
    });
};
```

Comment: `tokaci` is an array (filter returns an array) and you're not using it as an array.

Comment: i dont know how can i. I did the way in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give variables a clear name, this will increase the readability of the code. `member.user.username` is not a display name in the discord. Therefore, this approach does not replace display usernames. To get the display name, you can use the `displayName` property.
`tokaci` already return members collection, so you dont need use`tokaci.memebers`

Use role IDs, otherwise you will have to rewrite a huge part of the code, if the role is trivial to be renamed

---

```
exports.run = async (client, member, message, args) => {
    let tokuchi = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "tokuchi");
    let tokaci = message.guild.members.filter(member => {
        return member.roles.some(r=>["tokuchi"].includes(r.name));
    });
    tokaci.forEach(member => {
        if(member.manageable) {
            let newNickName = member.displayName.replace(`⍭`, '-');
            member.setNickname(newNickName)
            .catch(console.error)
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined

Comment: in let tokaci line

Comment: oh thank you its worked i got errors because we use "member" two times i changed and its worked